# Why does this large Java Project need common-ant.xml for building?

Tags: java, ant

This is the error when trying to build the Pet Store example:

```
C:\Users\user\workspace\common-ant.xml could not be found
BUILD FAILED
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\workspace\common-ant.xml
(The system cannot find the file specified)
```

The **common-ant.xml** part is making no sense. I have no idea why it says `common-ant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The install_dir/samples/common-ant.xml file defines properties common to all sample applications and implements targets needed to compile, assemble, deploy and undeploy sample applications. In most sample applications, the build.xml file includes common-ant.xml.

Found on a [tutorial here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19747-01/819-0079/dgenv.html)

Have a look at your `build.xml` file, the location may be declared inside. Then, read the pet store tutorial carefully (again), maybe there's a sentence where you're asked to copy some predefined common-ant.xml to some location.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a GWT project? If so, it requires to have a common-ant.xml. Google that file, and you'll see examples online.